# Manga/manhwa about a guy who enters into a tower and befriends little white fluffy monsters with sharp teeth who eat blue glowing rocks

Tags: story-identification, manga

The manga is about a guy who enters into a tower/portal/dungeon
(I forget) and the main purpose is to defeat the different levels within the different rooms/dimensions(?). From what I remember, the guy befriends these little white fluffy ball-shaped monsters with sharp teeth who eat these blue glowing rocks. He befriends them by acting like one of them and eating the rocks too. Throughout the manga, he takes them with him as he defeats other monsters and do whatever quests the rooms require the players to do.

Another thing I remembered is that the guy has seen a video of himself completing it before and at the end, those who made it are not allowed to talk about what has happened in the tower. Somehow though, he gets a video of himself from the future and is able to use what he knows although he pretends to be new and everyone just thinks he is lucky.

I believe the people who enter the towers are known as players or something similar to that. Another aspect I remember from the manga is that the guy is streaming his adventure to other people in the towers. There's a way where people can watch other players (I believe they can only watch players in lower levels than them? I'm not certain, just speculation) and can donate money and theres also live chat for those viewers.

Thats all I can remember so far. I was reading it earlier this year and it was still ongoing. I put it aside as I waited for an update and honestly forgot about it for a while since the update was quite slow and I got distracted by another manga/manhwa and animes. Anyways, thanks for any help i can get, much appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Is this ***[The Overpowered Newbie](https://myanimelist.net/manga/148458/The_Overpowered_Newbie)***...?

> With his orphanage on the brink of closure, Jaeju Kim needs to get rich fast. His best shot is to conquer the mysterious tower that appeared in the world seven years ago, except that few who enter the tower ever manage to return. Jaeju is just about at his wits' end when all of a sudden, he receives a bunch of videos featuring himself clearing the tower in the future! With his own comprehensive walkthrough in the palm of his hand, will this overpowered newbie be able to conquer the tower?
>
> [image: Promotional art for "The Overpowered Newbie."]

As mentioned in the synopsis above, a mysterious tower appeared in the modern world seven years ago. Select individuals are summoned into the tower through portals, and those few who return -- known as the 'Awakened' -- come back more powerful and attain wealth and fame.

The protagonist, Kim Jaeju, is a young man who works to earn money to help fund the orphanage he grew up in, but the orphanage needs more income and is at risk of closure. Kim wishes he were one of the Awakened, so he could make more money, and then receives a bunch of videos on his phone, showing his future self raiding the tower. These videos includes shots of small, furball-like creatures called popoi, that look a bit like [tribbles](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Tribble), except they're white and have faces. They're generally friendly, but have sharp teeth and enjoy eating blue mana stones.

Thanks to these videos, Kim knows he'll be summoned into the tower in two years' time, so he spends that time preparing himself to raid it, using the videos as a sort of strategy guide. When he eventually enters the tower, he encounters several popoi and becomes friendly with them, carrying three of them with him like pets.